# Growth of stable homotopy groups of spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let ${}_2\pi_n^S$ denote the $2$-power torsion subgroup of $n$th stable homotopy group of the sphere spectrum. Its order is a power of $2$: $$|{}_2\pi_n^S|=2^{k_n}.$$

**Question:** What is known about growth of $k_n$? Is it polynomial? What is the best estimation?

**Remark:** Of course, any estimation on ${\rm Ext}^{s,t}_{\mathcal A_2}(\mathbb F_2,\mathbb F_2)$ implies an estimation on $k_n.$ The Lambda algebra gives an exponential estimation, it is not interesting. I'm not very familiar with the May spectral sequence. Does it give a better estimation?

Comment: The full group or mod the image of j?  For the former it's going to be dominated by the image of j, which is a question about growth of Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Is that true? The order of the image of $j$ is the denominator of $B_{2n}/4n$. By the Von Stuadt-Clausen theorem, the denominator of $B_{2n}$ is a multiple of $2$ but not $4$, so the $2$-adic valuation of the order of the image of $j$ is $v_2(8n)=3+\log_2(n)$ and grows only logarithmically with $n$.

Comment: (Edit: whoops, this is a bound for the torsion exponent, not the size of the whole group- sorry!) I think the best that's known is in this paper by Akhil Mathew: https://msp.org/agt/2016/16-2/agt-v16-n2-p12-s.pdf. It provides an essentially sharp, universal bound for the torsion in the kernel of the Hurewicz homomorphism. At 2, the kernel is annhilated by 2^{(n/2)+3}. For the sphere itself perhaps one could improve on that, but I don't think anything qualitatively better than `k_n is roughly linear in n' is known.

Comment: I guess you could combine the estimate in the torsion exponent with the vanishing line for the Adams spectral sequence to get something like linear times logarithmic in n?

Comment: @WillSawin:  Looks like you're right, the small numbers were misleading about growth.  I should have actually looked at the growth of Bernoulli numbers before commenting

Comment: I want to mention a recent result of Burklund: The exponents of the stable homotopy groups grow at most linearly. See Theorem 3.8 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.14116.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is work by [Boedigheimer and Henn](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01171748.pdf) that bounds the size of *unstable* homotopy groups of spheres or rather of the number of $p$-local summands (i.e. the dimension after tensoring with $\mathbb{F}_p$). The bound is again exponential, namely $3^{q-n/2}$ for $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{F}_p}\pi_q(S^n)\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$. There is a slight improvement in later work by [Henn](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01172158.pdf), but the bound is still exponential as I understand it.

Looking at the data, the growth of the stable homotopy groups seems to be less than exponential though. According to [Isaksen's charts](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4983.pdf) (with possible miscounts by myself) the sequence of the first few $k_n$ is:

1 1 3 0 0 1 4 2 3 1 3 0 0 2 6 2 4 4 4 3 2 2 8 2 2 2 3 1 0 1 8 4 5 5
 5 1 2 3 9 7 5 5 3 3 7 4 10

Particularly big ones are $k_{15} = 6$, $k_{23} = 8$ and $k_{47} = 10$. The contribution of the image of $J$ is $5$, $4$ and $5$ respectively in these degrees. While the image of $J$ should dominate in low degrees, elements of higher Adams-Novikov filtration should become more and more dominant. All in all, the data does not really look like an exponentially growing sequence, but who knows with our limited knowledge?

Edit: I incorporated Allen Hatcher's corrections to my sequence of $k_n$.

Comment: A couple small corrections to the original list of $k_n$'s in this answer:  (1) Delete the third zero in the list to make the initial terms 1 1 3 0 0 1 4. (2) Change the pair 8 6 near the end of the list to 9 7.

Comment: Since this post has been bumped: one should also add the recent paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04247.pdf. Conjecture 2.2 there says that k_1 + ... + k_n = O(n^2), so k_n = O(n).

Comment: @skd I'm glad to hear there's an explicit conjecture along these lines! One quibble -- although $k_1 + \dots + k_n = O(n^2)$ implies that $k_n \sim n$ "on average", Isaksen-Wang-Xu don't actually conjecture that $k_n = O(n)$. I get the sense that they expect $k_n$ is "random" enough that $\limsup k_n / n$ might be $\infty$ (and $\liminf k_n / n$ might be 0), even though the sum $k_1 + \dots + k_n$ smooths this out and is $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 9):

Since posting the preprint Tim mentions, I found Iriye's 1987 paper `On the ranks of homotopy groups of a space'. Iriye says (Theorem 1 and Remark 2) that it is not hard to replace the $2^\frac{k}{p-1}$ in Tim's answer with a $3^\frac{k}{2p-3}$. This is slightly better than the bound I proved, and I suspect that the proof is cleaner (though Iriye doesn't give a proof, and I haven't checked it). I have updated the Arxiv submission to acknowledge Iriye. Of course, this is *still* an exponential bound.

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to MO! Since you're an expert on these things, I thought I'd ask about something I found peculiar -- the estimates that you and Henn get for the _unstable_ homotopy groups of spheres are obtained from _stable_ data using the EHP sequence. Is there any hope of getting better bounds on the _stable_ homotopy groups of spheres by bypassing the EHP sequence and just applying the same stable data directly?

Comment: Thank you! By stable data, do you mean that the input to both my and Henn's induction was in the stable range? I have no idea how one might try to bypass the EHP sequence, but I don't know much/any stable theory. Stability pops out because the EHP sequence 'knows' the stable range - if you put in that groups on negative stems vanish, then you get the the stable range. This means that the proofs naturally kick out bounds which stabilise. The proofs don't really have any contact with the stable groups 'as objects' - they just know that 'the unstable groups stop changing in the stable range'.

Answer (score 6):

A recent preprint of [Boyde](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.11872) improves this bound, showing that

$$\log_p(\#\pi_{n+k}(S^n)_{(p)}) \leq c_p 2^{k/(p-1)}$$

where $c_p = \frac{1}{4}2^{1/(p-1)}$

Note that this bound depends on $k$ and not $n$, so it stabilizes to show that

$$\log_p(\#\pi^s_{k}(\mathbb S)_{(p)}) \leq c_p 2^{k/(p-1)}$$

In his introduction, Boyde mentions some earlier results of Henn which are better than the ones that Lennart mentions, in that they depend only on $k$ and so stabilize. The citation is to the same single-author paper of Henn that Lennart links to.

Of course, this is still an exponential bound.

Answer (score 5):

A subexponential bound is available (using only things known 40 years ago).

Thanks to John Palmieri over [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385019/is-there-an-elementary-subexponential-upper-bound-on-the-size-of-the-stable-stem?) for pointing out that the $E_1$ term of the May spectral sequence is a *commutative* polynomial algebra and so ought to have graded dimension which counts some sort of partition, and for subsequently pointing out that on account of $h_{1,0}$, this observation must be supplemented with some information about vanishing lines in the Adams spectral sequence.

Indeed, the May $E_1$ term $V^{\ast\ast\ast}$ is a polynomial algebra in $h_{ij}$ for $i\geq 1, j \geq 0$, with tridegree $|h_{ij}| =(s,t,u) = (1,2^j(2^i-1),i)$, i.e. bidegree $(s,t) = (1,2^j(2^i-1))$ in the Adams $E_2$, i.e. degree $t-s = 2^j(2^i-1)-1$ in the stable stems. Note that $h_{1,0}$ has bidegree $(s,t) = (1,1)$; all other $h_{i,j}$'s have $t-s > 0$.

Let $W^{\ast\ast\ast} \subseteq V^{\ast\ast\ast}$ be the subalgebra generated by the $h_{i,j}$'s other than $h_{1,0}$. Keeping just the last grading $k = t-s$, we see that $\dim W^k$ counts the number of ways of partitioning $k$ using positive integers of the form $2^j(2^i-1)-1$, i.e. positive integers whose binary expression contains exactly one zero (since the numbers $i$ and $j$ are uniquely determined by the quantity $2^j(2^i-1)-1$). This is less than the total number of partitions, and hence subexponential. The estimate via total partitions tells us that $\dim W^k \leq \exp(c\sqrt{k})$ for some $c>0$, but since the allowed parts for partitioning are exponentially sparse like in the Steenrod algebra, I'd guess that an upper bound of the form $\dim W^k \leq \exp(c(\log k)^2)$ actually follows from this if one works through the combinatorics, [just as it does with the Steenrod algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110185v1).

Adding back in the generator $h_{1,0}$, we see that $V^k$ is infinite-dimensional for all $k$. But because the $s$-grading of $h_{1,0}$ is still positive, we can use the fact that the $E_2$ page of the Adams spectral sequence (which I'm just calling $Ext^{\ast,\ast}$) has a vanishing line, in the sense that $Ext^{s,t} = 0$ for $0 < t-s < 2s + d$ for some constant $d$. I believe this implies that every element of $Ext^{s,t}$ with $t-s = k$ can be written as a sum of monomials $h_{1,0}^a\prod h_{i,j}^{b_{i,j}}$ where $a < k/2 - d/2$, so that we essentially have $\dim (\oplus_{t-s = k} Ext^{s,t}) \leq \sum_{a=0}^{k/2} \exp(c\sqrt{k-a})$. Because subexponential functions are closed under integration, it follows that the Adams $E_2$ page already has subexponential growth, and hence that $\log_2 |\pi_k\mathbb S_{(2)}|$ likewise has subexponential growth.

There is an odd primary analog of this too. See Ravenel's green book for a version of the May spectral sequence at odd primes where the $E_1$ term is a commutative polynomial algebra.

The dimensions of the graded parts of $W^k$ start off, if I coded things correctly, as:

| degree $k$ | bound on $\dim W^k$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 11 |
| 7 | 15 |
| 8 | 21 |
| 9 | 28 |
| 10 | 38 |
| 11 | 49 |
| 12 | 65 |
| 13 | 83 |
| 14 | 107 |
| 15 | 136 |
| 16 | 172 |
| 17 | 215 |
| 18 | 269 |
| 19 | 332 |

This sequence must be well-known, as I think it is the basis for Bruner's Ext software. So I'm surprised that I can't find it in OEIS. Perhaps I have made a mistake.

---

Here is an earlier version of this answer:

Thanks to Nicholas Kuhn over [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385019/is-there-an-elementary-subexponential-upper-bound-on-the-size-of-the-stable-stem) for pointing out that the dimension of the Lambda algebra can be used to bound the size of the $E_2$ term of the Adams spectral sequence.

The dimensions of the graded pieces of the Lambda algebra appear in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A049285 and a bit of searching reveals that Tangora computed the asymptotics in [Level number sequences of trees and the Lambda algebra](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(13)80019-4), where I think he also considers the odd-primary case. Unfortunately, the results are stated in terms of generating functions, and a quick look has not allowed me to find a place where he actually states the asymptotic upper bound he gets on the dimension of the Lambda algebra. But his work is based on Flajolet and Prodinger's [Level number sequences for trees](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(87)90137-3), and if I'm deciphering things correctly, it looks like the bound is still exponential.

Comment: I think you are wrong about the lambda algebra being the same size as the Steenrod algebra.  It is the Koszul dual of A with $Sq^0=0$., so it should have `opposite' relations. (Another description: it is the same as the Dyer Lashof algebra without unstable restrictions.(

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Ah, you're right, thanks. In the Steenrod algebra, $Sq^{i_1}\cdots Sq^{i_s}$ is admissible iff $i_r \geq 2 i_{r+1}$, whereas in the $\Lambda$-algebra, $\lambda^{i_1}\cdots \lambda^{i_s}$ is admissible iff $2 i_r \geq i_{r+1}$. So it definitely looks "dual". I'm hopeful that its size can still be compared to some sort of partitions and thereby be seen to be subexponential.

Comment: I may be doing something silly -- it would seem to follow from the above that $\pi_0 \mathbb S_{(2)}$ is finite, which is of course false...

Comment: The element $h_10$ is in the zero stem, as are all of its powers. In positive stems, you may need to combine the May SS with the Adams vanishing line to get a good bound on the size of each stem.

Comment: (Just like in the Lambda algebra, $\lambda_0$ is in the 0-stem, so you need to be careful when using $\Lambda$ to bound stem sizes.)

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks. I stupidly did not save my code, so I will forever wonder what it was actually computing so that it missed that $deg(h_{10}) = 0$. A naive, spectral-sequence-neophyte question: Since $h_{10}$ is is the 0-stem, does it suffice to bound the size of the subalgebra generated by the other $h_{ij}$'s on the one hand, and on the other hand to use any old bound for the exponent of $\pi_k \mathbb S_{(2)}$? Or is there room for more extension problems, so that one really needs to know about vanishing lines in the Adams spectral sequence?

Comment: I think there could be extensions, so it's safest to use the vanishing line. This is Theorem 3.4.5 in Ravenel's green book. I don't think you need to be too careful about the intercept, so the key thing is that the slope is 2 (or 1/2 or maybe even 1 depending on how you label the axes). See also figure A3.1 in Ravenel.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks -- this was very educational for me! I actually did not know that the $E_2$ page already had a vanishing line -- I was under the impression that all vanishing lines were deep things appearing on the $E_\infty$ page and related to nilpotence.