# Asymptotics of Hilbert series for locally finite free graded-commutative algebras?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $A^\bullet$ be an $\mathbb N$-graded algebra over a field $k$, and let $d_A(n) = \dim A^n$ be the dimension of the $n$-th graded piece, so that $P^A(t) = \sum_n d_A(n) t^n$ is the Hilbert-Poincare series for $A$. I'm interested in obtaining asymptotics for $d_A(n)$ as a function of $n$ in the case where $A$ is a free graded-commutative algebra on infinitely many generators, but where there are only finitely many generators in each degree. That is, I'm interested in $A$ of the form

$$A = k[x_1,x_2,\dots] \otimes \Lambda[y_1,y_2,\dots]$$

where $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ is the polynomial algebra on generators $x_i$ and $\Lambda[y_1,y_2,\dots]$ is the exterior algebra on generators $y_i$, where $deg(x_i) \to \infty$ and $\deg(y_i) \to \infty$ as $i \to \infty$ (and $\deg(x_i)$ is even while $\deg(y_i)$ is odd).

Essentially, this means that $d_A(n)$ counts certain types of partitions of $n$, with restrictions related to the degrees of the generators $x_i,y_j$. I imagine there are some general techniques available for obtaining such asymptotics.

The particular $A$ I'm interested are certain subalgebras of the $E_1$ term of the [May spectral sequence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/May+spectral+sequence) at a given prime $p$. In the case $p=2$, there is a single generator in degree $n$ for each $n \geq 1$ such that the binary expansion of $n$ contains at most one zero. In the case of odd $p$, there is a polynomial generator in degree $2n$ whenever the base $p$ expansion of $n$ is all "1"'s except for at most one zero, and there is an exterior generator in degree $2n-1$ for the same $n$.

Thus in the cases I'm interested in, the number of generators in degree $\leq n$ grows as $\log(n)^2$. I'm aware of [old work of Pennington](https://doi.org/10.2307/1969735) which obtains asymptotics when the number of generators grows as $\log(n)$, and I know this [can be used](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110185v1) to show that $d^A(n) = O(\exp(c\log(n)^2)$ in this case. Unfortunately this doesn't quite cover the case I'm interested in.

**Question:** Let $A = k[x_1,x_2,\dots] \otimes \Lambda[y_1,y_2,\dots]$ be a free graded-commutative algebra where there is at most one generator in each degree, (and I'm particularly interested in the case where the number of generators in degree $\leq n$ is $O(\log(n)^2)$). How can one attain an asymptotic upper bound for $d^A(n) = \dim A^n$, as $n \to \infty$?

(In fact, for the application I have in mind, it suffices to know that $d^A(n) = O(\exp(cn))$ for all $c>0$, so the crude upper bound $d^A(n) = O(\exp(c\sqrt n))$ given by comparing to counting *all* partitions actually suffices for what I want to do. But It would be nice to know something a bit less crude.)

Comment: I should add that the motivation for this question is that I want to get a subexponential upper bound on the size of the stable homotopy groups of spheres, following the line of thought that John Palmieri and Nicholas Kuhn suggested when I brought it up [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385019/is-there-an-elementary-subexponential-upper-bound-on-the-size-of-the-stable-stem). I think I fleshed out their suggestions enough [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385081/2362) to get the bound I want, but again it would be nice to have it in a less crude form.